# using reusable content in a site collection migrated from 2007 to 2010

Tags: migration

We migrated our existing 2007 site collection to 2010, then created a new 2010 "team-site" under it.

I want to use "reusable content" in this new sub-site, but I can't get it to appear in my Lists.  I have tried disabling & re-enabling the "sharepoint server publishing" features on the site collection & the new sub-site, but it made no difference.

Is there something else I need to do, or is it just a Bad Idea to have a 2010 site sitting in a 2007 migrated site collection?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the you should enable " SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature at Site Collection Level and not the "sharepoint server publishing" at site level. Once you enable it, the list that you are looking for will be created in the Root web of the site collection.

Comment: hmmm, but I want to have different "reusable content" in each of my sub-sites - is that no longer possible?

Comment: not possible via out of the box features. As usual, you can create your owen feature to create the list at web level.